# J2ME getDisplay get null pointer exception

Tags: java-me

I have a form, that include 2 functions to call 2 canvases, when I am displaying second canvas it is throwing error `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make your Display variable "mf" as `static` in the [code snippet you originally posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8131315/1).